# spring integration for lightweight messaging asyn invocation

Tags: messaging, spring-integration

I am planning to use Spring Integration as my lightweight messaging solution avoiding JMS or MQ. My requirement is when an event A happens there should process B and C triggered asynchronously with some inputs supplied by A. It will not be a single JVM so I am planning to use JDBC message-store.

- Is SI best tool to solve this?
- How difficult is it to maintain our message store that backs pollers (*need to write our own polling SQL query?*) .
- Will it create table contentions while deleting message from the persistent table?
- How to ensure that the thread pool is effectively utilized?

Comment: I don't understand "It will not be a single JVM so i'm planning to use JDBC message-store" how are those two related exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using JDBC for distribution rather than persistence, you'd be better off distributing the event to the other JVMs using a lightweight adapter such as UDP or TCP.